# How to add clear input field option and refresh option list after clearing?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this HTML form example https://jsfiddle.net/j8re1cqa/

```html
<form id="mainForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="uniqueItem" list="itemlist">
  <datalist id="itemlist">
      <option data-value="10010">Placeholder name</option>
      <option data-value="10006">Random name</option>
    </datalist>
  <input id="sendButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How do I add a right-aligned icon inside input field to clear the input data? There is an `X` in MS Edge, but there is no clear button visible in Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox, the drop-down list is not even loading before you start typing.

When I delete the input data using backspace, the drop-down list refreshes only after I also left-click into the input field again. This feels really awkward and redundant. How to auto-refresh list when the interest keyword has more options again or when input field is empty?

Comment: `input[type="search"]` will add a clear icon by default.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with jQueryflexdatalist library: [projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/](https://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/)
It offers easy implementation and styling, something the default datalist can't do well.